# How to start a mock server in my ProviderService and call a webservice?

Tags: pact

How to create a mock server to call a webservice in my providerservice class.

I created the clientPactTest class with some interactions, created json file, published it, but got stuck at the Verfication part in the ProciderService.
In my scenario i have to call a webservice in my Provider service. Its a typescript project.

Please answer my queries:

1) Right now iam running my webservice at command line at localhost port 8080. Then I created a ProviderService with a Pact mentioning the provider url and hostname as localhost and port 8080. So that all my tests hit the webservice which I started at command line. Is this the right approach?

2) Iam a bit confused as at many websites its mentioned that we dont run the actual service for pacts verification and we should create a mock server. So if I create a mock server, do i have re write all the endpoints in my providerservice file, the way it is mentioned in the actual webservice ?

Please clarify.

Thanks,
Aruna

Answer (score 1):

With provider side verification you always need to run the real provider to ensure it behaves as expected by its consumers. On the consumer side you use the mock service in place of the provider, so perhaps this is where the confusion lies.

In the case where your provider service also is a consumer of another service, the pattern repeats itself.

See https://docs.pact.io/best_practices/provider#only-stub-layers-beneath-where-contents-of-the-request-body-are-extracted and related sections on that page.

The general advice is that you should use local stubs for any downstream service(s) during pact provider testing

Comment: Thanks Matt for clarification.
My Webservice which I intend to call in my Provider Service is a seperate component which we usually run at commandline through package.json script. It starts a nodemon and all other associated services.
My question is how should I call this webservice programmatically in my ProviderService class. My project is in typescript. I saw some sample examples on the web in java they use some other set of API's. Any sample code in typescript or node to call a webservice through ProviderService, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Or shall I start my webservice manually at commandline and then start my Provider service mentioning the same host and port name as that of the webservice?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you mean by `ProviderService` - I think you mean the code that runs the Provider pact verification. There is no e2e TypeScript example, but it's trivial if you look at the JS example here: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/blob/master/examples/e2e/test/provider.spec.js

Comment: Great! Did my answer help at all? If so, could you please up vote it?